# Get Access Token from Azure AD backed .NET Framework MVC app

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have a .NET Framework MVC application that has authentication configured for session based Azure AD.  After a user logs in, I need to obtain an access bearer token and refresh token for the front end to use for Power BI javascript embedding.  I am unable to figure out a way to obtain an access from the server for this purpose.

Here is how Start.Auth.cs is set up:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions ());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri                    
            });
```

I need a user based authentication access token to pass to Power BI javascript embedding so that the user is identified, not a client id / client secret server based token.

Answer (score 0):

There is a .NET Core sample provided by the PowerBI team.

[https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/../NetCore-Sample/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/.Net%20Core%20Sample/NetCore-Sample/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs)

There is also more documentation on how to get the authorization code when you look at

- [Get Azure AD Access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried the core example in my project, but new users get a redirection loop and finally land on the login.microsoft.com page, with the message "Pick an account.  We couldn't sign you in"